# Ubuntu user permissions for working with resilio sync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sync

Hi i have a simple setup where my ubuntu workstation syncs with some other devices via resilio sync.

I've successfully got it working using [these](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-resilio-sync-ubuntu-16-04-16-10) instructions.

However my problem is that once i do any modifications from my external device. The updated or new file will have such permissions that my normal non root user wont have write access to the file anymore...

There is a different user used by sync `rslsync` i've added my user to its group and added that user to my users group... still cant get this working.

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huil5.png)

In this screenshot you can see the file `untitled copy.txt` is write accessible to my user `vach` but other two are not.

How can i do such that anything written by `rslsync` is also fully accessible rw for user `vach`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like the answer to this. In my case, it's files written on windows can not be written when shared with linux.

I am forced to do a chmod -R 777 every time windows writes a file.

Comment: what i ended up doing with linux, i've changed rsync user to my own user, so when files are written by resilio they are actually written by my user... not sure how that will interact with windows though...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Go to .service file 
`sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/resilio-sync.service`

Change this lines with your current user name:

User=aurelien.izoulet 
Group=aurelien.izoulet 
Environment="SYNC_USER=aurelien.izoulet" 
Environment="SYNC_GROUP=aurelien.izoulet"

Restart systemctl :  
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload` 
Then restart rslsync service and this should works!